# Would It be possible to declare any member of catholic hierarchy an anathema?

Tags: catholicism, excommunication

Let's go for an extreme case and consider, for example, that the Pope started behaving in absolute opposite ways to te catholic doctrine.

Even with him being the head of the catholic church. Could people of lower hierarchy declare him as such if he were to behave like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question and relevant to current events. There is some debate on what would happen with a heretic pope. I think the majority opinion is that a pope who professes formal heresy ceases by that act to be pope automatically. There is both scriptural precedent and precedent in Church history for bishops and others in the church hierarchy rebuking the pope for wrong teaching. You might find [this article on the dubia helpful](https://onepeterfive.com/cardinal-burke-a-pope-who-professes-formal-heresy-would-cease-to-be-pope/), it touches on your question.

Usually, you wouldn't lose your office for misconduct as pope (though the pope can punish anyone else for misconduct), but you could definitely be rebuked. There's plenty of precedent for that. If Cardinal Burke is correct, and I believe he is, a Pope preaching formal heresy would immediately cease to be pope, however, and could and should be replaced by the college of cardinals once he has done so.

Comment: Canon1404 debunk your answer, and Cardinal Burke is automatically excommunicated by openly,repeatedly and continuously violating Canon751 and Canon752, thereby merited Canon1364

Comment: Can 1401, to which 1404 is referring, does not mention heresy. It is speaking of spiritual matters (ie how one is living) and matters of ecclesial law. If the Pope preaches heresy, he's a heretic, plain and simple. I said *in my answer* that the Pope can't be punished by others for misconduct, which appears to be the essence of 1404. I've never once seen Cardinal Burke violate either canon 751 or 752, that's a tall claim. You have some evidence of this, I presume? Since he hasn't, to my knowledge, violated these canons, canon 1364 doesn't apply.

Comment: Here's the proof, the fish got caught on his mouth. https://wherepeteris.com/cardinal-burke-this-is-an-opinion-of-pope-francis-as-a-man/

Comment: Pope Francis hasn't taught infallibly that Catholics cannot support the death penalty, nor that it is intrinsically evil, which is what his revision to the Catechism seems to imply, so I don't think Burke is being disobedient here. He *definitely* isn't espousing defined heresy. Good faith Catholics can disagree with the Pope about some things, including cardinals without breaking their vows. If/when Francis tries to define this teaching of his *ex cathedra*, we will be able to assess who is correct more accurately (btw that might make him a heretic and no longer pope ;)

Comment: Read Canon752, the likes of  Cdl.Burke are subject to Donum Veritiatis which he is openly, repeatedly and continuously violating.

Comment: Could you explain how Burke is in violation of Donum Veritatis, in detail? Merely disagreeing with the Pope's changes to the catechism or his personal beliefs regarding capital punishment are not sufficient. Pope Francis presents an unorthodox view of capital punishment, and has only ever done so in non-official teaching capacities (this includes the catechism revisions). If this is all you have, you have failed to show Burke is guilty of any wrongdoing. Catholics, including Cardinals, may disagree with the Pope's personal views.

Comment: Read Canon752 and the guidelines of Donum Veritatis, and tell us if a bishop or cardinal is allow to express a contrary opinion publicly on approved Magisterial Teachings like CCC2267 and spread falsehood that its only Pope Francis opinion when the CDF approved it. Therefore its not a personal opinion of Pope Francis anymore, when CDF affirmed and approved the changes, right? So, Cdl.Burke is guilty of spreading falsehood.

Comment: The simple fact is that the catechism is not an infallible document, and it is not a means by which the pope exercises infallible teaching. Therefore, disagreement and indeed revision is possible. Burke also makes the point that the language used is not theological, and thus that the "inadmissible" qualifier is meaningless, which is a quibble about what the revision actually means rather than disagreement with the revision itself. But if thinking that Francis doesn't have the best interests of the Church at heart and sometimes teaches erroneously makes one a heretic, then anathematize me, too.

Comment: Have you read Canon752? How about Donum Veritatis? If not yet, then, your are not intelligently speaking, Read it first.,